# Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using driver.findelement by.classname method to read an element on firefox browser but i am getting "Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results." exception

here is my code

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bighead crb")).Text.Trim().ToString()

//and here is how the html of browser looks like

<form action="#" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="return false;">
    <section id="lx-home" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
  <div class="bigbanner">
    <div class="splash mc">
      <div class="bighead crb">LEAD DELIVERY MADE EASY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, your own answer isn't the best one in terms of your question.

Imagine you have HTML like this:

```
<div class="bighead ght">LEAD DELIVERY MADE HARD</div>
<div class="bighead crb">LEAD DELIVERY MADE EASY</div>
```

`driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bighead"))` will find both and return you the first `div`, instead of the one your want. What you really want is something like `driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bighead crb"))`, but like you said in your question, this won't work as you need another way to find elements by compound class names.

This why most people use more powerful `By.CssSelector` or `By.XPath`. Then you have:

CssSelector (the best):

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".bighead.crb")); // flexible, match "bighead small crb", "bighead crb", "crb bighead", etc.
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class*='bighead crb']")); // order matters, match class contains  "bighead crb"
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class='bighead crb']")); // match "bighead crb" strictly
```

XPath (the better):

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@class, 'bighead') and contains(@class, 'crb')]")); // flexible, match "bighead small crb", "bighead crb", "crb bighead", etc.
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[contains(@class, 'bighead crb')]")); // order matters, match class contains string "bighead crb" only
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='bighead crb']")); // match class with string "bighead crb" strictly
```

Comment: CSS Selectors are definitely the way to go on this one. They are very powerful.

Comment: @user1177636 thank you for this example. I will surely implement it in my automated test scripts soon.

Comment: i tried to implement both CssSelector and XPath. For some reason CssSelector is not able to find the element, but XPath works. I think i will use XPath going forward. Thank You for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Figured out this problem, you have to search by:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bighead")).Text.Trim().ToString(); //instead of 
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("bighead crb")).Text.Trim().ToString();
```

any space in html class represents a new class name so just search by the first word.

Comment: The better way would be to use CSS selectors, this is what they are there for in the first place.

Comment: @Arran can you give an example how to use css selector in this situation? i wanna move away from using id and classnames