# How do you select a button using chrome driver based on class name only?

Tags: c#, selenium, web

I am using Selenium Chrome driver/ C# to select buttons on a website. They don't have id tags only the class tags. How do I select these types of button.

Usually I would do something like this if I have the Id.

```
 var _SignInButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SignInButton"));
_SignInButton.Click();
```

Example of one these buttons class name is

```
class="button-71444407 blue-3811567280"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361643/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-consider-searching-for-one-class-name-an)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _SignInButton =
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".button-71444407.blue-3811567280"));
```

See also Selenium Documentation
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

**EDIT:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.button-71444407.blue-3811567280"));
```

Should find all buttons with class value `button-71444407` and `blue-3811567280`

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='button-71444407 blue-3811567280']"));
```

Should find exactly that button and all other buttons with class value `button-71444407 blue-3811567280` (order of values matters)

```
driver.FindElement(
  By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'button-71444407 blue-3811567280')]"));
```

Should find exactly that button and all other buttons with class value containing `button-71444407 blue-3811567280` (order of values matters)

Comment: I think the answer is correct. it is just not working for me, in this particular application. here is the button html: <button color="blue" data-qa-id="package-0-bottom-select" type="button" class="button-71444407 blue-3811567280 selected-3003004324"><!-- react-text: 22 -->Selected<!-- /react-text --><svg aria-labelledby="title" class="icon-3484217708 icon-3873154517" focusable="false" height="14" role="img" width="14"><title></title><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-checkmark"></use></svg></button>

Answer (score 0):

Select exactly same with the class name:

```
ChromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class = 'button-71444407 blue-3811567280']"));
```

Everything name that contains in:

```
ChromeDriver.FindElement(.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'button-71444407 blue-3811567280')]"));
```