# Element having a class only and I am unable to click on "OK"

Tags: java, class, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How do I click on the following button "OK" using XPath:

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//button[@class='btn btn-primary crtBtn btn btn-default']");
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the error? Check if the button is inside an iframe?

Comment: Error no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='btn btn-primary crtBtn btn btn-default']"}

there is no iframe. just a lightbox appear just after login

Comment: Try below xpath:
`By.xpath("//button[.= 'Ok']")`

Comment: Also HTML has composite class, check this thread for composite class element [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361643/compound-class-names-are-not-supported-consider-searching-for-one-class-name-an)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this xpath :

```
.//button[@type='button']
```

Also put wait as  **Thread.sleep** before clicking this element.